# hg update error

Tags: mercurial

I am getting the following error when trying to run `hg update`:

```
abort: Operation not permitted:
/var/www/simira/web/public/images/nominations/13/big/4f196667cf5a2.jpg
```

Here is some info:

```
$ cd /var/www/simira/web/public/images/nominations/13/big/
$ ll ./4f196667cf5a2.jpg 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 martin portadesign 15356 Feb  2 22:10 4f196667cf5a2.jpg
$ ll -d ./
drwxrwxr-x 2 martin portadesign 4096 Feb  2 22:10 ./
$ id
uid=5004(clime) gid=5007(portadesign) groups=5007(portadesign),10(wheel),48(apache)
```

Tell me what is wrong, please...

Comment: do you have write permission for the file?  (are you "martin"?)

Comment: no, but i am in group portadesign

Comment: hmm, file permission issues is the only thing I can think of.  I would try to see if you can overwrite the file manually.  Otherwise, I have no idea.

Comment: `Operation not permitted` is the POSIX error `EPERM`, which is not the same as `Permission denied` (`EACCES`), so this is not a file permissions issue. I don't think the given info is sufficient to determine the true cause, though (what a poor error message...)

Comment: @larsmans: Mercurial don't have much more information than the error from the OS. But you're right that it would be nice to print the context in which the error was thrown. A not-so-user-friendly way it to add `--traceback` to get the full traceback. That shows there the exeption was thrown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was caused by hg attempting to change the permissions of the file:

```
$ sudo hg update
$ ll ./4f196667cf5a2.jpg
./ -rwxrwxr-x 1 martin portadesign 15356 Feb  2 22:10 4f196667cf5a2.jpg
```

As can be seen, it added executable bit to the image. That is the only bit that hg acually tracks and there does not seem to be a "switch-off" option. The problem is that only an owner of the file can change its permissions.

Comment: I've had this problem a lot, a quick `chown` and everything went smooth. Thank you for answering.